# How to share directory with Fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mount, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a fargate container running which needs access to files present on an EC2 instance. Both are in the same network and security groups do not restrict traffic.

I tried using `sshfs` as well as mount using `cifs.utils` package. However because it is a container I get errors during the mount

```
Unable to apply new capability set.
```

or

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

I checked the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402218/fuse-inside-docker, but this involves having access to docker host. And my setup is not on hosted ECS.

Is there a way to make the contents of a directory on an ec2 instance available on a Fargate container?

Comment: I wonder if you could rearchitect so shared files are on EFS https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

For your case [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) (see "Server Support" and "Client Support" section) seems to be a viable solution because of the flexibility you can have on EC2 instance. On Fargate which is a controlled environment, you can built client tools into your image that can interact with the server **over the network**, eg. HTTP, FTP, sFTP etc.